# Failed to access embedded resources

Tags: c#

I am failed to access embedded resources. I'm using this document as a reference https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa970069(v=vs.100).aspx

The code

```
res = new Uri($"pack://application:,,,/{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name};component/language_default");
```

gives `System.IO.IOException: Can't find "language_default" resource`, but it exists in the resources:

[image]

Comment: What's the connection between `default_language` and `language_default`?

Comment: @Itay I tried to hide the original's file name :) Edited my question, the names are the same.

Comment: Is it possible that `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name` is a different assembly to the one with the Resource file?

Comment: @NielsFilter i doubt it, but how can I be sure it's not a different assembly?

Comment: @NielsFilter the `Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name` returns the same assembly name where `language_default` is embedded to

Comment: Is your resource file and the place where you create the `Uri` in separate assemblies?

Comment: @NielsFilter, nope, same assembly

Comment: I tried the using your `Uri` and created a Resource file and it worked fine. Perhaps change the `Access Modifier` drop down on the Resources tab to `Public`?

Comment: Silly question, you are using c# 6 syntax. Are you indeed using c# 6? because if you're not, then `{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}` isn't translated to the name of your assembly, but stays `"{Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name}"`

Comment: @NielsFilter yes, i'm using c# 6 for sure. The output of `Console.Write(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name)` gives my assembly's name.